# Referencia de métodos que devuelven valor

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Evaluar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int x,y ;
        double f;
        System.out.print("Ingrese numero: ");
        x = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese numero: ");
        y = teclado.nextInt();
        f = (factorial(x))/((factorial(y))*(factorial(x-y)));
        System.out.print(f);
    }
    public static int factorial(int n){
        int i, fact;
        if (n == 0 ){
            fact = 1;
        } else {
            fact = 1;
            for (i = n; i>=1; i--){
                fact = fact*1 ;
            }
        }
        return fact;
    }
}
```

Necesito evaluar esta función (X!)/(Y!(X-Y)!) Factorial de X se divide entre el factorial de Y multiplicado por el factorial de X-Y. Los datos X y Y deben solicitarse y leerse. Si me pueden ayudar el resultado es incorrecto

Comment: Seguro de la función factorial? `for (i = n; i>=1; i--){ fact = fact*1 ; }` no pinta bien si además fact comienza como 1 y nadie más lo modifica. Suena a un largo 1*1*1*1*1

Comment: ya encontre el error. fact = fact * 1, en vez de 1 es i.

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta y acéptala luego

Answer (score 1):

El problema me parece el calculo del factorial, si deseas obtener el factorial de un numero debes multiplicar los números enteros positivos que hay entre el 1 y el número especificado.

Ejemplos,

el factorial de `3`:
1*2*3 teniendo como resultado `6`

el factorial de `5`:
1*2*3*4*5 teniendo como resultado `120`

el factorial de `10`:
1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10 teniendo como resultado `3628800`

tu método esta recibiendo este valor y va a realizar la multiplicación el número de ocasiones de acuerdo al numero definido iniciando con el valor de 1:

```
 public static int factorial(int n){
        int i, fact;
        if (n == 0 ){
            fact = 1;
        } else {
            fact = 1;
            //realiza la multiplicación el numero de ocasiones de acuerdo al numero definido.
            //Iniciando con 1
            for (i = n; 1<=i ; i--){
                fact = fact * i ;
               //fact = fact*1 ; //*Incorrecto, siempre dará 1 como resultado.
            }
        }
        return fact;
    }
```

---

Esta sería otra versión para calcular el factorial de un número:

```
 public static int factorial(int n){         
     int factorial = 1;
     while (n != 0) {
        factorial=factorial*n;
        n--;
     }    
    return factorial;         
 }
```